# 'undefined reference to `shogun::SGRefObject::unref()' when compiling with .so object

Tags: shogun

I'm getting this error when I try to compile the gaussian kernel test given on the shogun developer page at
https://github.com/shogun-toolbox/shogun/wiki/README_developer.
I followed the instructions given in order to produce the `.so` shogun library at https://github.com/shogun-toolbox/shogun/wiki/INSTALL.
I then went to the directory above that containing the shared object library and issued the order `"g++ GTest.cpp shogun/libshogun.so -o a.out"` and was given the error that is the topic of this post.
I ran through a thread linked on the net (2 link restriction), but I couldn't find a given  solution.
Anybody have any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

you shouldn't try to link directly the shared library with your example.
Say you created a shogun based example file, let's call it `shogun_example.cpp`, in order to compile this you should run:

`g++ shogun_example.cpp -o shogun_example -lshogun`

this is in case the `libshogun.so` is in the search path of the linker.

If the compiled `libshogun.so` is not in the search path then you should provide the location of the shared library to the compiler with `-L`, for example:

`g++ shogun_example.cpp -o shogun_example -L<path to the shogun shard lib> -lshogun`

Comment: Unfortunately, this didnt work. I am using the instruction "g++ -std=c++11 -DHAVE_EIGEN3 classifier_gaussian_process_binary_classification.cpp -o classgp -lshogun" in an attempt to compile the example within the examples folder and am getting a laundry left of undefined references. I set each of the g++ include search variables to the /usr/local/include folder within which shogun stored its include folder after installation. I also set up the LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable so that shogun would be able to find the shared library. I can compile other examples and I have installed eigen 3 with apt-get

Comment: Solved the problem. Turns out OpenCL is a dependancy and it's something I overlooked because I didn't read the text as I was installing the shared library's with cmake. Lesson here is to read cmake instructions while installing, regardless of how simple instructions on a site make installation out to be lol. Thanks for putting up with me.